# calendarview past date color

Tags: android

I have 2 fields where I select the start and the end date for the event, so that the condition accords to "start date less than end date".

I need to change a non valid date's color, with the above mentioned condition (start date starts from todays date), I have a style for the calendar view as shown below

```
       android:id="@+id/calendarView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
       android:theme="@style/CalenderViewCustom"
       android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText"/>


<style name="CalenderViewCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
       <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
       <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
       <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/title_color</item>
   </style>

   <style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
       <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
       <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/white</item>
       <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
   </style>

   <style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
       <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
       <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>

   </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this style in your datePicker XML -

```
<style name="PickerDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>

<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/DatePickerStyle</item>
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primDark</item>
```

```
<style name="DatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
<item name="android:headerBackground">@color/prim</item>
<item name="android:calendarTextColor">@color/primDark</item>
<item name="android:dayOfWeekBackground">@color/primDark</item>
<item name="android:yearListSelectorColor">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:datePickerMode">calendar</item>
<item name="android:minDate">01/01/2000</item>
```

Comment: bro please read the question carefully, setting the minimum date wont change the color but onclick will be disabled for past minimum dates @Abishek

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to customize your calendar for any requirements then please go
```

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

it may helps you.